# How to add a shutdown shortcut similar to Alt+F4 in windows

Tags: shortcut-keys, 17.04

by pressing the shortcut (Alt + F4 ) I must get the shutdown or restart option.

I have no idea about that shortcuts in settings

[image]

Comment: I made a python project using PyQt5 as I also liked that windows feature and Linus does not provide it I made a blog showing how to set up it I hope that might help you
[Blog Link](https://rudracoder.blogspot.com/2022/12/shutdown-window-in-linux-altf4.html)

Answer (score 0):

You must

1. Select `Custom Shortcuts`
2. Click to `+` button (Appear a window that have name and command input
   box)
3. Type a name in `Name:` input box (everything you like) and in the
   `Command:` input box type `gnome-session-quit --power-off`
4. Click to `Add` button
5. A field created. Click it and press every shortcut (example `super + q` )

Don't forget you have several seconds to choose or cancel it otherwise it will be shut down automatically.